# Evaluating a Difficult limit!

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, complex-numbers

I have to evaluate a very complicated limit, I've done this task already but I wanna make sure I did it right. The function I have in my hands is

$$
F(\omega)= \tanh \Big[a\cdot V_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(1-\frac{\omega^{2}}{V_{0}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big]-2i\omega \cdot \frac{(1-\frac{\omega^{2}}{V_{0}})^{\frac{1}{2}}}{V_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-2\frac{\omega^{2}}{V_{0}})}  \,\, ,
$$

Where $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, $a$ and $V_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$. The limit is the following:

$$
\lim_{a\to 0} F(\omega) \quad  \textrm{and} \quad \lim_{V_{0}\to \infty}F(\omega) \,\, ,
$$
So,

$$
F(\omega)=\lim_{a \to 0, V_{0} \to \infty} \tanh \Big[a\cdot V_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(1-\frac{\omega^{2}}{V_{0}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big]-2i\omega \cdot \frac{(1-\frac{\omega^{2}}{V_{0}})^{\frac{1}{2}}}{V_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-2\frac{\omega^{2}}{V_{0}})}  \,\, . $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second term goes to $0$ as $V_0\to\infty$, independent of $a$. But the hyperbolic tangent function's double limit is not well-defined: it depends on the speeds at which $a$ approaches $0$ and $V_0$ approaches $\infty$. If $V_0$ is fixed (or growing slowly compared to $a$'s convergence to $0$), then the $\tanh$ term approaches $0$; but if $a$ is fixed (or shrinking slowly compared to the growth of $V_0$), then the $\tanh$ term approaches the sign of $a$.

Comment: @GregMartin, What Do you mean with " then the $\tanh$ term approaches the sign of $a$"? What's the value assumed by the function $\tanh$ in that limit?

Comment: I mean that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \tanh(ax) = 1$ if $a>0$, while $\lim_{x\to\infty} \tanh(ax) = -1$ if $a$ is negative.